# Error message when installing android package apk

Tags: android, apk

I generated the apk of my project but when I try to install it, this happens:

[image: Screenshot of android phone screen, showing a popup message titled 'Error de análisis'. The text: 'Se ha producido un error al analizar el paquete' is shown below, with a single 'Aceptar' button]

"error reading packages"/"
error analysis"

Comment: how you build it? you need to make a signing key and build it with that key. And make sure your phone/emu doesnt violate your app minimal android API requirement

Comment: I use my signing key and say that the apk was generated successfully. The problem is when I install it and the problem was on 5 smartphones

Comment: what is your min API? can you post your gradle build or android manifest?

Comment: API 22 Lollipop 5.1.1

Comment: How can I do it compatible with all APIs?

Comment: Please, I need help with this problem

Comment: can you post your manifest and gradle build?

Comment: These are the build.gradle and AndroidManifest: http://subefotos.com/ver/?8fdc42cde878ac9a213040d21e083dc6o.png       http://subefotos.com/ver/?be4b5408a81675a64925b839220c2f3co.png